# How to copy all text in a WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, copy-paste

I've a WebView and a button and i want to automatically copy all the text in the WebView on click of the button without having to long press the WebView and manually select and copy. Is this possible and how do i go about it

Comment: Does answer help you?

Comment: @Danial what answer?

Comment: The answer, below